# Grouping and subsetting by Category Data Frame

Tags: r

I have a dataset, which is called "DF".
[DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7xwg.png)

I would like to make a table like the picture below.

[Data Table what I want to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trTe9.png)

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data is named `df1`, here is one possible solution:

```
library(data.table)

df2 <- as.data.table(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) c("", x)), by = Category]
df2[, cyl := fifelse(seq_len(.N) == 1, Category, ""), by = Category]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I want! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(purrr)
 library(tibble)
 df1 %>%
   group_split(Category) %>%
   map_dfr(~ .x %>% add_row(Category = '', .before = 1))
```

Comment: @akrun. Thank you for the link. Very useful!